# Change the first and second text input value when they don't have an ID

Tags: javascript, input, text, onclick, userscripts

I know how to change the text input value with javascript if they have IDs, but what if they don't have IDs? I need to find and change the value of the first, and second text input on the page. How would I do that?

```
<input type="text" id="text" value="no value">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Change Values</button>

function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("text").value = "Text is now changed";
}
```

I need to know how to change the first and second input text's value on the page if they don't have an ID. For example, change "no value 1" to "yes value 1", and "no value 2" to "yes value 2". How would I do that?

```
<input type="text" value="no value 1">
<input type="text" value="no value 2">
```

Comment: Simplest should be use good old FORM tag around and then just index - document.forms[0][0 or 1] or you can use names instead of indexes too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, using document.getElementsByTagName is one answer.

```
const inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
inputElements[0].value = "insert input 1";
inputElements[1].value = "insert input 2";
```

check this jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/hentleman/09tr7bku/1/)

Comment: Do we have to use const? Can we use var instead?

Answer (score 0):

Old school, but still works:

```js
function changeEm() {
document.forms[0][0].value = "yes value 1";
document.forms[0][1].value = "yes value 2";
}
```

```html
<body onload=changeEm()>
<form>
<input type="text" value="no value 1">
<input type="text" value="no value 2">
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many document elements query methods, one of them is `document.getElementsByTagName`.

This method returns an `HTMLCollection`, which is an iterable of HTML objects.

Having this knowledge, let's say you have the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Get Inputs</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" value="First" />
  <input type="text" value="Second" />
</body>
</html>
```

You could get all the `input` elements in your HTML using `document`'s `getElementsByTagName` as follows:

```
const inputEls = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

`inputEls` will contain a `HTMLCollection` of `HTMLInputElement`, now we are able to iterate the collection and do something with it.

The final JavaScript must look like the following:

```
const inputEls = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for (let input of inputEls) {
  // Here you are able to access every input element of te collection
// And consume HTMLInputElement object
  console.log(input.value);
}
```